# pyQt GroupBox alignment

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've got a real problem in making the alignment of the header of QGroupBox when i change the width of a border.

Initially i have something like this:

First filter

[image]

And when I change stylesheet of this groupbox

```
self.filter.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox {border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black; text-align: left;}")
```

The header of the filter "goes down" like this:

Second one

[image]

Is there any way to set centered alignment for bold frame of the groupbox?

Comment: Though I didnot achieve success but I ccan help a little self.groupbox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox {border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: black; text-align: left;} QGroupBox::title {left:50px; bottom : 6px;margin-top:2px;}").Try adjusting the property QGroupBox:title. I was able to lift up the header but the above text got hidden

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after a long search I came up with this, try it:

```
QGroupBox#nameOftheGroupBox{
    border: 1px solid rgb(13, 33, 212);
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

QGroupBox:title#nameOftheGroupBox{
    left: 16px;
    bottom: 7px;
}
```